# $.getJSON syntax issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, flickr

I'm about to rip out my eyes and eat them. I'm trying to pull data from flickr and apparently I have no idea what I'm doing.

This works:

```
var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/api_key=xxxxx";
$.get(flickrAPI, 
{
method: "flickr.photosets.getList",
format: "json",
user_id: "xxxxx"
}, alert("ok")
);
```

And I am alerted "ok"
However when I try to use function() {} in place of alert()...

```
var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/api_key=xxxxx";
$.get(flickrAPI, 
{
method: "flickr.photosets.getList",
format: "json",
user_id: "xxxxx"
}, function(data) {alert("ok");}
);
```

Nothing happens.

Also, if I assign the return value of $.get to a variable, I'm left with the following JSON object:

```
{"readyState" : "1"}
```

which is not what I'm looking for. any ideas? It might be worth noting that the html file I'm working with is a local file.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the request using your developer tools? Probably a same origin issue.

Comment: aha! same origin issue it is. I didn't even know that was a thing. thank you so much for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: I just created an answer containing some more information, you might want to check it :)

Comment: Your alert runs ONLY because it is executed immediately BEFORE the flickrAPI call is even sent.  You will need to use JSONP to communicate with flickr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve data from another host using AJAX because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

It may be possible to use `jsonp` if the other host supports it. It is explained how to use `jsonp` with jQuery in the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). In the specific case of Flickr there is a [blogpost](http://blog.michaelhamrah.com/2010/02/using-flickr-and-jquery-to-learn-jsonp/) explaining how to use jsonp with flickr.

Comment: oh awesome. thanks for that link, you are the man! I'm also kind of assuming that running this all from file:/// could be a big part of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since it is API I asume it has Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so this should work

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/api_key=xxxxx",
  data: {
    method: "flickr.photosets.getList",
    format: "json",
    user_id: "xxxxx"
    },
  success: function(data) {alert("ok");},
  dataType: "json"
});
```