# How to retrieve a json from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to write a HTML5 mobile application and use jQuery to get a json from the url 
http://cin.ufpe.br/~rvcam/favours.json I tried using

```
var url='http://cin.ufpe.br/~rvcam/favours.json';
$.getJSON(url, function(data, status)
    {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
    });
```

but nothing shows up on the console. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

**[EDIT]** I learned from another post that I can't normally retrieve information from another server. But this server in particular (cin.ufpe.br/~rvcam) is mine. Can I use PHP or some other method to allow my application to retrieve the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$.getJSON syntax issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584061/getjson-syntax-issue)

Comment: Try adding a [`.fail()` callback](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) and see if it's raising an error. The arguments will match `$.ajax()`'s `error` option -- `(xhr, status, error)`.

Comment: Since the file is [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), as others have mentioned, you can try requesting it with [`$.getScript(url);`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of `$.getJSON()`. You'll have to define a global `function foo(data) { ... }` to receive and handle the `data` since the file will try to call it.

Comment: So I can't use $.getJSON with cross-domain calls?

Comment: @user2918054 It is possible, [depending on the clients you need to support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors). But will require 2 edits: The "*padding*" of `foo()` will need to be removed from the file so that it's just JSON and the server will need to [respond with CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) that allow the request.

Comment: `$.ajax(url, {dataType:"jsonp",jsonpCallback:"foo"}).done(function(data) {...});` will tell jQuery to expect jsonp with the callback name `foo`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski that is strange for me. I'm following an intel tutorial which says
"Use $.getJSON() whenever you need to retrieve JSON data from a remote domain that does not support CORS."
and
You can make cross-domain JSON-P requests from jQuery using the 
$getJSON method illustrated below:

    'var url='http://someurl/someAppServerService.php?';
    $.getJSON(url + 'method=somemethod&callback=?', 
    function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
    );'

Comment: If you hardcode the callback name, then you have to use `$.ajax` and explicitly set the function name to be used. Have a look at the documentation. FWIW, it looks like you modified the data of file, so now it's neither valid JSON nor JSONP. *edit:* JSONP is not a silver bullet. It only works if the server supports JSONP.

Comment: @nnnnnn what if I want to let Ajax chose the callback name?

Comment: @rvcam: Then you have to configure your server so that it can read the callback name from the URL and create the response dynamically. That won't work though if you are using a static file for that data.

Comment: @FelixKling that is exactly what I am looking for! How do I do that? Could you point me to some useful material?

Comment: It all depends on which server side language you are using. You only have to know how to encode data as JSON and how the retrieve the GET arguments from the HTTP request.

Comment: @FelixKling oh and please put your information as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL doesn't return valid json. It returns some JavaScript that attempts to execute a function called "foo" and passes the object as an argument. This is commonly called "jsonp". It is a method of achieving cross domain ajax calls

Comment: And how would I use $.getJSON to make these cross domain ajax calls?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/   if you take a look at the section here for "jsonp" and "jsonpCallback" you  should be able to figure out how to define foo and get the data

Answer (score 2):

Your `http://cin.ufpe.br/~rvcam/favours.json` file isn't valid json. The valid json is wrapped in `foo()`. Remove the `foo()` from that file and it will work.